# Wrapping list item tags <li></li> with an <ul> tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a tool that marks up text with HTML without the need to do it manually.

Currently the tool takes text copied into a rich text editor and outputs the HTML after a bunch of .replace regex patterns are used to clean up some common issues.

One issue I cannot seem to solve is converting lists as it's pasted from MS word. Here's what it looks like from MS word:

```
<p>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum dolores.</p>
<p>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum dolores.</p>
<p>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum dolores.</p>
<p>·&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum dolores.</p>
```

I was able to convert this, via regex, so that each is wrapped with a list item, but I cannot figure out how to wrap the list items in unordered list tags.

For example, I'd like to change

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

into

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I can't get the regular expression to match. Here's what I'm using:

```
.replace(/(?<!<\/li>)<li>/, "<ul><li>")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: No. What is the purpose of this answer? Are you suggesting I shouldn't use regex for this?

Comment: @Dpuiattiv That's right.

Comment: @Dpuiatti yes, regex should not be used to parse HTML. Can you give more information on your particular situation and why you're trying to do this, and maybe we can provide an alternative solution?

Comment: @Dpuiatti you should use a parser to parse HTML. Something like [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) might be what you need

Comment: @Bodacious I'm trying to build a tool that marks up text with HTML without the need to do it manually. I was able to convert list items from MS word so they are wrapped in <li>'s but now I need to add a ul to them.

Comment: You might try `.replace(/^<li>.*<\/li>(?:[\r\n]+<li>.*<\/li>)*$/gm, '<ul>\n$&\n</ul>')`

Comment: This feels like the purpose of [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegExps with HTML is typically a bad idea. I personally would use DOMParser and alter the HTML with DOM methods. If you have only one one group of lis, it is as simple as selecting and appending them to a UL.

```js
var str = `
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
`
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
var body = doc.querySelector('body')
var lis = doc.querySelectorAll('li')
var ul = document.createElement('ul')
body.insertBefore(ul, lis[0])
lis.forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li))
console.log(doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
```

If there can be more than one list, you need to find the groupings and add multiple uls.

```js
var str = `
<li></li>
<li></li>
<p></p>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<p></p>
<li></li>
`
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
var body = doc.querySelector('body')
var lis = doc.querySelectorAll('li')
var groups = Array.from(lis).reduce((groups, li, index, arr) => {
  if (index === 0 || li.previousElementSibling !== arr[index-1]) {
    groups.push([])
  }
  groups[groups.length-1].push(li)
  return groups
}, [])
groups.forEach(lis => {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul')
  body.insertBefore(ul, lis[0])
  lis.forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li))
})
console.log(doc.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test.replace(/<li>[\s\S]*<\/li>/g, function(x){ return "<ul>"+x+"</ul>";})
```

and here's the snippet that show how it works:

```js
var test = `sdf df s
sdf sfs
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
sdsfdsfsd`;
console.log(test.replace(/<li>[\s\S]*<\/li>/g, function(x){ return "<ul>"+x+"</ul>";}))
```

Comment: also you can replace `[\s\S]*` with  `(.*)` for the eager RegEx.